# Filtering date between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to filter the data between two dates.
But i am not able to achieve

Where the Detaileddata is my array having set of data. In which I have the date as

`date = {01.07.2020,02.07.2020,03.07.2020,.....18.08.2020}`

where date has the values in the format **[DD.MM.YYYY]**,
But the result i am able to acheive is only the data having **01.07.2020** and **18.08.2020**. But I want to display the data between the **01.07.2020** and **18.08.2020**

**Typescript part**

```
     var startDate = "01.07.2020";
     var endDate = "18.08.2020";
     this.Detaileddata = this.Detaileddata.filter((item) => {
       return (item.date >= startDate && item.date <= endDate);
     })
     console.log("result"+this.detaileddata);
```

Comment: You can convert the dates to timestamps and after that, you can accomplish this filtration. You can use libraries like day.js or moment.js for the conversion. 
Also, you can check functions like `isBefore`, `isAfter` in these libraries, then you won't need to convert them to timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way always to use library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Using vanilla approach. You can convert date in timestamp. I am assuming you are getting these date:

```js
var startDate = "01.07.2020";
var endDate = "18.08.2020";

const detailedData = [{date:"01.07.2020"},{date:"20.07.2020"},{date:"25.07.2020"},{date:"01.08.2020"},{date:"18.08.2020"},{date:"01.09.2020"},{date:"01.10.2020"}]

const filteredDate = detailedData.filter(item => {
        let itemDate = item.date.split('.').reverse().join("-")
        let startDateModified = startDate.split('.').reverse().join("-")
        let endDateModified = endDate.split('.').reverse().join("-")
       return (new Date(itemDate).getTime() >= new Date(startDateModified).getTime() && new Date(itemDate).getTime() <= new Date(endDateModified).getTime());
     })
console.log("result",filteredDate);
```

Comment: new Date(endDate) is invalid date as the browser read "18" like a month. You have to use proper format to be able to filter them like that.

Comment: Yep. Got Output. Very Fast reply